# Display Element count without button

Tags: javascript, html

Im trying display the count of the childnode in the html page, is there anyway I can display the count without using  button onclick function, html page:
`<span id="demo"></span> <button type ="button"onclick ="test()">click</button>`

```
function getCount(){
  var nodeToCount = document.getElementById("overall-page");
  var questionCount = document.getElementsByClassName("survey-form");
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = questionCount.length;
  console.log(questionCount.length);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are many events you can use...

https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_events.asp

What do you want to achieve? it could run on window load? mouse hover over the area?

Comment: I think should be window load cause I wan it displayed as soon as the HTML page load

Comment: so on the body tag, you need to include onload="getCount"

Comment: there's also the window.onload event if you prefer not using dom event inline